# How to highlight node in TreeView ? Not only text area, but all row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`TreeNode.Select()` doesn't work. I want it to be highlighted like

[image: pic1]

All that I have is

[image: pic2]

Comment: There is a treeview.fullrowselect but I can't remember offhand if it includes the left margin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use TreeView.FullRowSelect property for this. But remember, it is ignored if ShowLines is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

```
TreeView.FullRowSelect Property 

Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selection highlight spans the width of the tree view control.

public class CustomizedTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public CustomizedTreeView()
        {`enter code here`
            // Customize the TreeView control by setting various properties.
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CadetBlue;
            FullRowSelect = true;
            HotTracking = true;
            Indent = 34;
            ShowPlusMinus = false;

            // The ShowLines property must be false for the FullRowSelect 
            // property to work.
            ShowLines = false;
        }

        protected override void OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            // Confirm that the user initiated the selection.
            // This prevents the first node from expanding when it is
            // automatically selected during the initialization of 
            // the TreeView control.
            if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
            {
                if (e.Node.IsExpanded) 
                {
                    e.Node.Collapse();
                }
                else 
                {
                    e.Node.Expand();
                }
            }

            // Remove the selection. This allows the same node to be
            // clicked twice in succession to toggle the expansion state.
            SelectedNode = null;
        }

    }


follow this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.padding?view=netframework-4.7.2
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)